# How to use CSS combination of mix-blend-mode and isolation?

Tags: html, css, mix-blend-mode

I have a parent element with a red background. I want an h2 element to blend just some words with the background, and other words, inside a span tag, no.

My example below is not working.
How to make it work?

```css
.bg-red {
  background: red;
}

.blend {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color: white;
}

.isolate {
  isolation: isolate;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-red">
  <div class="blend">
    <h2>This text should <span class="isolate">(This one shouldn't)</span> be blended 
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tqnvruv7/4/)

Comment: A few notes: To add to Temani Afif's answer (which worked for me!) be sure to not use any z-index on the mix-blend-mode elements as they will no longer display correctly. I have also found that pseudo elements will also not inherit blend modes.

Answer (score 8):

In order to make it working you need to specify the isolation **before** applying the `mix-blend-mode`. So between the background and the text on where you will apply `mix-blend-mode` you need to have a wrapper where `isolation` is set.

Here is an example where the background is applied on the `h2` and inside we have many `span`. We apply `mix-blend-mode` on them and we wrap the non-needed one with another wrapper where we apply `isolation`:

```css
h2 {
  background: red;
}

h2 span {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color: white;
}

.isolate {
  isolation: isolate;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  <span>This text should</span>
  <div class="isolate"><span>(This one shouldn't)</span></div>
  <span> be blended</span>
</h2>
```

But if you apply `mix-blend-mode` on the h2 you won't be able to isolate any of its content:

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}

h2 {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

h2 span {
  color: white;
}

.isolate {
  isolation: isolate;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <h2>
    <span>This text should</span>
    <div class="isolate"><span>(This one shouldn't)</span></div>
    <span> be blended</span>
  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not make much sense to me, this way I could just ignore the isolate property and write this: 
h2 span:not(.isolate) {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color: white;
}

Comment: @raphadko yes you can :) i simply explained how the isolation work [how i understand it] ... i didn't focus on the html, but i focused on how it should be used in order to work

Comment: @raphadko the conclusion of this, is that if you already apply mix-blend-mode to parent element, you cannot remove it from child element using isolate