# Weird `mix-blend-mode` Behaviour, Changing When Parent's Height Is Set To `100vh`

Tags: html, css, mix-blend-mode

I noticed some weird `mix-blend-mode` behaviour, see here:

```css
body {
  background: blue;
}
main {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background: blue;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  top: 2rem;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<main>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</main>
```

Now the `div`s don't blend with the `body`, only with each other and with `main`.  But when I set the height of `main` to `100vh`, suddenly the `div`s blend with the `body`.  Is this a bug in Chrome?
Here is how it looks in my browser with the code above:

[image]

And here with `height: 100vh` (note that the width is unchanged):

[image]

Even when the `main` has no background at all its height changes the `mix-blend-mode` between the `div` and the `body`!

Anyway, I'd like to have `div`s in some container so they only blend with each other, not with the container background.  Is this possibly, across browsers?

Comment: set a background color to the html element to avoid background propagation and you should have the same result across browser

Comment: Thanks a lot.  But having the elements blend in each other but not with the background is *only* possible with background on body, not on a parent element?  (Because that's the effect I want...)

Comment: you are probably looking for isolation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49807419/8620333

Comment: Awesome!  I played around and it seems I need another element in between, is this correct?  So `<main><section><div/><div/></section></main>` and then i put `isolate` on `section`?  Because `isolate` on the `div`s didn't lead to the result...

Comment: you can use it on the main element

Comment: But then it blends with `main`, I'd like them to blend with each other, but neither with `main` nor with `body`...

Answer (score 0):

This is the difference that occurs depending on whether or not "background: blue" is applied to the wrapper(ex. body) of the main.

Comment: Did you try setting the height of `main`?  Did you also get different blending results for `100vh` vs something like `50vh` or `5rem` or is this only in my browser?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).